# Improving Performance of Inflating data by generating missing sequential data

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a dataset which has missing data - around 10,000 to 500,000 rows.

```
1 2 3 13 14 15 18 26 ...
```

I need to fill the data in between so that it is continuous for subsequent processing.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 ...
```

I have tested 2 ways of inflating the data:

```
import time
df = pandas.DataFrame([['Sam']], columns=['Name'])
```

I create an array then do a join:

`Time(ms) Taken to load : 3.886`

```
start_time = time.time_ns()

times = [ time for time in range (100)]
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(times, columns=['Nos'])
df['key'] = 'key'
df2['key'] = 'key'
df3 = df2.merge(df,on='key')

print('Time(µs) Taken to load :', (time.time_ns() - start_time)/1000)
```

Using dataframe - merge on individual records:

`Time(ms) Taken to load : 285.757`

```
start_time = time.time_ns()

interim = pandas.DataFrame()
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for ts in range (100):
        row['Nos'] = ts
        interim = interim.append(row)

print('Time(µs) Taken to load :', (time.time_ns() - start_time)/1000)
```

Clearly the first approach is faster by a factor of 95.

- Is there a faster way to do this while using dataframes?
- When there are several 1000s of intermediate Nos to generate the `append` will slow things down. Maybe I can hold it in memory till a certain size and then push it through. Is there any other way of speeding this up on dataframes?
- Can I use an approach in Python similar to Matrix Multiplication which is optimized for vector processing so that I can generate the all the other repeating fields in an array or list. This is to replace the join in the first approach so that I can hold the data temporarily in memory.

```
[1(Row) x 1] [ 1 x 100 (Nos) ] = [ 1 x 100 (1 Row Repeated 100 times with this new Nos) ]
```

- Is there a way to generate this array, `[ time for time in range (100)]`, without iterating over a range?

Comment: Look at the first example in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly I was looking at something like this - this runs 23 times faster. Not tested on the entire dataset though!

```
# Optimization 2: Try out using Numpy array :
start_time = time.time_ns()
start_time_s = time.time()

delta = 100
times = numpy.arange(start = start_time_s, stop =start_time_s + delta, step = 1)
times= numpy.expand_dims(times,1)
# print(times)

base = numpy.array(['Sam', 'Dam', 'pam'])
base= numpy.tile(base, (delta, 1))
# print(base)
result = numpy.concatenate((base, times), axis=1)

print('Time(µs) Taken to load :', (time.time_ns() - start_time)/1000)
print('Time(s) Taken to load :', time.time() - start_time_s)
```